# Optional parameter odata function c#

Tags: c#, odata

I define a function for GeminiTickets like this:

```
var geminiTickets = builder.EntitySet<GeminiTicket>("GeminiTickets");

        var geminiTicketsParam = geminiTickets.EntityType.Collection
            .Function("GetNewTickets")
            .Returns<ReportDataVM>();
        geminiTicketsParam.CollectionParameter<int>("projectIds");
        geminiTicketsParam.Parameter<DateTime?>("startDate");
        geminiTicketsParam.Parameter<DateTime?>("endDate");
```

in GeminiTicketsController...

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetNewTickets([FromODataUri] List<int> projectIds, DateTime? startDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null) {...};
```

When I want to access this function with all parameters, everything is fine:
http://example.com/odata/GeminiTickets/Service.GetNewTickets(projectIds=[1,2,3],startDate=2016-06-10,endDate=2016-06-22)

But if I send no parameter at all of if I try to send e.g. only projectIds, IIS gives me a 500 Internal Error:
[http://example.com/odata/GeminiTickets/Service.GetNewTickets(projectIds=[1,2,3])](http://example.com/odata/GeminiTickets/Service.GetNewTickets(projectIds=[1,2,3],startDate=2016-06-10,endDate=2016-06-22))

I found that we can set a parameter to be optional:

```
geminiTicketsParam.Parameter<DateTime?>("startDate").OptionalParameter = true;
```

But it's doing nothing. Any idea ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OptionalParameter means it can be null, you can try with

```
startDate=null,endDate=null
```

Comment: Yeah at the end I did this. So I have to check each parameter in javascript, look if there is a value. If not, I just fill the parameter with null. That's bad because I have to load all parameters definition from the database even if I just really need the value from parameters that are set by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register both options for you function. One with all parameters and other with just one.

```
geminiTickets.EntityType.Collection
            .Function("GetNewTickets")
            .Returns<ReportDataVM>();
        geminiTicketsParam.CollectionParameter<int>("projectIds");
        geminiTicketsParam.Parameter<DateTime?>("startDate");
        geminiTicketsParam.Parameter<DateTime?>("endDate");


geminiTickets.EntityType.Collection
        .Function("GetNewTickets")
        .Returns<ReportDataVM>();
    geminiTicketsParam.CollectionParameter<int>("projectIds");
```